# No matching signature for operator IN for argument types ARRAY<STRING>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'd like to execute the following Standard SQL using "WHERE xxx IN ('aaa','bbb')".

But error has occurred.
Is it possible to use 'IN' in STANDARD SQL?

Standard SQL

```
SELECT commit, author.name, committer.name, committer.time_sec,
committer.tz_offset, committer.date.seconds , subject, message,
repo_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE repo_name IN 
('tensorflow/tensorflow', 'facebook/react')
```

Error

```
No matching signature for operator IN for argument types ARRAY<STRING> and {STRING} at [5:17]
```

The following Legacy SQL seems OK to execute.

Legacy SQL

```
SELECT commit, author.name, committer.name, committer.time_sec,
committer.tz_offset, committer.date.seconds , subject, message,
repo_name
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits] 
WHERE repo_name IN 
('tensorflow/tensorflow', 'facebook/react')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

In case if you need to preserve original records and just output those with 'tensorflow/tensorflow', 'facebook/react' in repo_name:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT commit, author.name AS author_name, committer.name AS committer_name, committer.time_sec,
committer.tz_offset, committer.date.seconds , subject, message,
repo_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(repo_name) name WHERE name IN ('tensorflow/tensorflow', 'facebook/react') 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your daily support. Every time, I have a lot to learn from you. Also I appreciate  the stack over flow and GCP support team!

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do like that in Standard SQL. But in this article [How to use the UNNEST function in BigQuery to analyze event parameters in Analytics](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-the-unnest-function-in-bigquery-to-analyze-event-parameters-in-analytics-fb828f890b42) they explain it very well.

This is how you get the result you are looking for I think:

```
SELECT commit, author.name as author_name, committer.name as committer_name, committer.time_sec,
committer.tz_offset, committer.date.seconds , subject, message,
repo_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(repo_name) as repo_names_unnested
WHERE repo_names_unnested IN ('tensorflow/tensorflow', 'facebook/react')
```

Note that you can't have both `author.name` and `committer.name`, since both will then be displayed as `name`. Therefore I changed them to `author_name` and `committer_name`.

I also think what you're actually is looking for is the result of replacing `repo_name` with `repo_names_unnested`, so try out replacing that as well in the SELECT-clause.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've done by replacing repo_name with repo_names_unnested in select clause as you suggested.

Comment: Great @YukioTakagi ! If it worked please mark my answer as a correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

Field 'repo_name' is REPEATED (Legacy SQL) or ARRAY (Standard SQL) which IN operator doesn't support for Standard SQL. To convert an array into set of rows, you my use [UNNEST operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest).